# Selection.copy then insert row only with formulas

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to insert a new row only with `Formula` after selecting a cell in Excel.

This is what I'm trying to do

```
Sub InsertNewRow()
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

The result of the code above is inserting a new row, but with all the values and formulas that has been copied. Is there a way to delete all the values and to maintain only the formulas?

Edit

Following @Tom advice I've came to a point

```
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
Selection.Insert
Selection.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

But it still copy all the values and formulas, is there a way to copy only the formulas and delete the values?

Comment: take a look at `.PasteSpecial` or `AutoFill`

Comment: I just want to ask you @Tom. Should I `Copy` `Insert` then `PasteSpecial`?

Comment: Yes. Copy the row that you want. Insert the number of new rows then paste to that destination

Comment: Thank you I will give it immediately a try.

Comment: You can use `Range.SpecialCells` to isolate values and clear them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, test the next code. No need to select in code...

```
Sub InsertNewRow()
   Dim rng As Range, cel As Range

    Set rng = Range(ActiveCell, Cells(ActiveCell.row, Cells(ActiveCell.row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column))
    rng.Copy
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    For Each cel In rng
        If Not cel.HasFormula Then cel.ClearContents
    Next
End Sub
```

Edited: And the next variant (shorter and more elegant, due to that...):

```
Sub InsertNewRow()
   Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Range(ActiveCell, Cells(ActiveCell.row, Cells(ActiveCell.row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column))
    rng.Copy
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: After trying for 5 hours, I can tell you now... I think I love you. Really nice

Comment: @ChangeWorld: Glad I could help! I edited the code answer and added a shorter variant...